# Proving $\lim_{n \to\ \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+3)k!} = e-2$

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+2)!} \leq \lim_{n \to\ \infty}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+3)k!} \leq \lim_{n \to\ \infty}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}   -2 $$

This is what I came up with but the problem is that the upper bound is practically identical to lower one. Is there any way to found bounds of summation to solve questions involving 'e'?

Comment: $$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+2)!} = 
\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{1!}
$$

Comment: **Hint.** Note that $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{x^{k+3}}{(k+3)\,k!}&=\int_0^x\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{t^{k+2}}{k!}\,\text{d}t\\&=\int_0^x\,t^2\,\exp(t)\,\text{d}t=(x^2-2x+2)\,\exp(x)-2\,.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By indeterminate coefficients we find the decomposition

$$\frac1{(k+3)k!}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{(k+3)!}=\frac2{(k+3)!}-\frac2{(k+2)!}+\frac1{(k+1)!}.$$

The omitted terms in the $e$ series total

$$2\left(\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac12\right)-2\left(\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}\right)+\frac1{0!}=2$$ and $$2-2+1=1.$$

Comment: can you explain you figured out the decomposition? I don't understand how to do it

Comment: @DDD4C4U: do you know the method of indeterminate coefficients ?

Comment: I have not heard of it

Comment: Can I get reference for this please? I can;t find it

Comment: Solve $$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{(k+3)!}=\frac a{(k+3)!}+\frac b{(k+2)!}+\frac c{(k+1)!}$$
by identification.

Comment: why did you choose those terms?

Comment: What do you mean when you say identification

Comment: @DDD4C4U: multiply both members by $(k+3)!$ and see.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series of $e^x$:

$$ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Multiply by $x^2$:

$$ x^2 e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k+2} }{k!}$$

Integrate both sides:

$$ x^2 e^x - 2 [ xe^x - e^x] = C+\sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty} \frac{ x^{k+3} }{(k+3)k!}$$

Evaluate both side at $0$

$$ 2e^0 = C$$

Or,

$$ C=2$$

Our answer is the integrated series evaluate at $x=1$:

$$ e-2[e-e] = 2 + \sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty} \frac{1}{(k+3)k!}$$

$$ e-2 = \sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty} \frac{1}{(k+3)k!}$$

Q.E.D